# MongoDb conditional grouping

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two fields for a vote poll like `vote1` and `vote2` which hold a `candidateId`. What I was trying to do is, calculate the number of vote counts for each `candidate` in my `VotePoll` collection.

My VotePollSchema looks like the following:

```
VotePollSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: true,
    },
    vote1: {
      desc: "First Voted Candidate",
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Candidate",
      type: String,
    },
    vote2: {
      desc: "Second Voted Candidate",
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Candidate",
      type: String,
    },
    isActive: {
      desc: "is Active.",
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
      required: true,
    },
});
```

What I want to achieve here is that count the number of votes for a candidate which might be in `vote1` or `vote2`. Since each `User` is able to vote for one or two candidates at the same time.

So, how should I group this collection by the candidate? Which could be either in `vote1` or in `vote2`. I've tried something like this but I don't think it's the appropriate way of doing it.

```
 const votePolls = await VotePoll.aggregate([
      { $match: { isActive: true } },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: {
            $or: [{ firstVotedCandidate: "$firstVotedCandidate" }],
          },
          voteCount: { $sum: 1 },
        },
      },
 ]);
```

My expected result:

```
{
   candidateOne: {
      candidateName: "Joshua Solomon"
      voteCount: 140
   }
   candidateTwo: {
      candidateName: "Jenny Doe"
      voteCount: 25
   }
   ...
}
```

Sample input data:

```
[
  {
    "isActive": true,
    "user": {
      "fullName": "Joshua Solomon",
      "createdAt": "2021-08-02T13:33:14.584Z",
      "updatedAt": "2021-08-02T13:36:35.041Z",
      "registeredBy": "61026c5e4fd8a53c98b8c579",
      "id": "6107f4182e21a42bd8b2b9cb"
    },
    "vote1": {
      "isActive": true,
      "fullName": "Candidate 1",
      "title": "Available Candidate",
      "createdAt": "2021-07-28T12:35:27.868Z",
      "updatedAt": "2021-07-28T12:35:27.868Z",
      "id": "61014f0f8d0ad041c0cf493a"
    },
    "vote2": {
      "isActive": true,
      "fullName": "Candidate 4",
      "title": "Fourth Candidate",
      "createdAt": "2021-07-28T12:36:13.229Z",
      "updatedAt": "2021-07-28T12:36:13.229Z",
      "id": "61014f3d8d0ad041c0cf4940"
    },
    
    "createdAt": "2021-08-02T13:36:34.859Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-08-02T13:36:34.859Z",
    "id": "6107f4e22e21a42bd8b2dae2"
  },
  {
    "isActive": true,
    "user": {
      "fullName": "Jenny Doe",
      "createdAt": "2021-08-02T13:33:15.351Z",
      "updatedAt": "2021-08-03T06:10:53.632Z",
      "registeredBy": "61026c5e4fd8a53c98b8c579",
      "id": "6107f4192e21a42bd8b2d136"
    },
    "vote1": {
      "isActive": true,
      "fullName": "Candidate 4",
      "title": "Fourth Candidate",
      "createdAt": "2021-07-28T12:36:13.229Z",
      "updatedAt": "2021-07-28T12:36:13.229Z",
      "id": "61014f3d8d0ad041c0cf4940"
    },
    "vote2": {
      "isActive": true,
      "fullName": "Candidate 2",
      "title": "Second Candidate",
      "createdAt": "2021-07-28T12:35:56.425Z",
      "updatedAt": "2021-07-28T12:35:56.425Z",
      "id": "61014f2c8d0ad041c0cf493c"
    },
    
    "createdAt": "2021-08-03T06:10:53.389Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-08-03T06:10:53.389Z",
    "id": "6108ddedcc1c4f2a505b4028"
  }
]
```

Comment: can you show the expected result?

Comment: Can you add an input example?

Comment: @J.F. updated with sample input now

Comment: what is `candidateOne` and `candidateTwo` fields? there is only single user in both object.

Comment: @turivishal it is the voted candidate whether in `vote1` or `vote2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This aggregate will return results in a sorted array:

```
[
  {
    '$addFields': {
      'votes': [
        '$vote1', '$vote2'
      ]
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$votes'
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': {
        'name': '$votes.fullName'
      }, 
      'voteCount': {
        '$sum': 1
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'candidateName': '$_id.name', 
      'voteCount': 1, 
      '_id': 0
    }
  }, {
    '$sort': {
      'voteCount': -1
    }
  }
]
```

The $addfields the vote fields into an array,
The $unwind separates the documents based on the votes,
The $group gets the voteCount, it will get the total votes regardless of whether they were the first or second vote
The  $project is just to clean things up
And the $sort is to sort the array from most votes to least.

I think you'd be best suited by changing your schema, vote1 and vote2 store practically the same information so you could simplify by having a schema where you store votes as an array of objects:

```
VotePollSchema = mongoose.Schema({
user: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: "User",
  required: true,
},
votes: [{
  desc: String,
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: "Candidate",
  type: String,
}],
isActive: {
  desc: "is Active.",
  type: Boolean,
  default: true,
  required: true,
},
});
```

Then you could avoid the $addFields at the start